# Entity Framework 5 Code First using ComplexType Entity or standard one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am working on an `ASP.NET MVC 4` application using `EF 5` and `Code First`. Part of my user interface are those three views :

[image: Simple menu picture]

Where each menu load a different information. However The information for both three menus represents a download link like this :

[image: Download link]

It's just that some files are referred to `Taxes` other to `Reports` and some to `Contracts` but in the core it's the same download link, with the same info and all.

Due to the fact that there are a lot of similarities I decided to make my entity like this:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int MenuID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsContract { get; set; }

    public bool IsTaxes { get; set; }

    public bool IsReport { get; set; }

    public int? ParentID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

Where `Documents` holds the information for the actual file like name and other stuff I need. But then I saw this option to use `ComplexTypes` and I start to wonder. Is it better to redo my entity using `ComplexType` and how exactly I can do this since I just saw the option but I'm not sure how exactly it's working.

The other option I see is just to have different entitues for `Taxes`, `Reports` and `Contracts` but this seems less optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Complex types](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/11/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-part-1-one-to-one-associations.aspx) are a special kind of 1:0..1 mapping, so I don't see how it could apply to your 1:n association.

It certainly makes sense to subtype `Document` in `Taxes`, `Reports`, and `Contracts` if this is a more or less rigid classification. But if document types come and go, or documents frequently change type, subclassing is of no use. But anyhow **it's the `Document` that knows its type**, not a menu.

A `Menu` is a UI element and it should not contain `Document`s. A business domain should be completely independent of UI implementations.

In the controller you connect the business domain (the model) and the view. Thus, when the Contracts button is pressed I suppose the controller will collect contract documents. This could either be done by

```
context.Douments.OfType<Contract>()
```

or

```
context.Documents.Where(d => d.Type == "Contract")
```

depending on whether or not you will apply subtyping.